# Is Google indexing HTML custom data attributes?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I'm building an AJAX based portfolio module using pushState / hash bangs and as I'm ruling out browsers without JavaScript the only thing that concerns me is how limited the HTML custom data attributes are when it comes to SEO.

For example, using the code below:

```
<ul class="gallery" data-anchor="/photography/example/" data-title="Example"></ul>
```

Will the data-title be indexed, i.e. will that text content be gathered by Google? Or would I need to include a header tag in or around the list as a descriptive complement? The data-title is meant to be used as a new window title once the user clicks on that particular gallery.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...are you opening a new window?  As in, are you opening a new browser window or making a "pseudo-window" within the page itself?

Comment: No, just changing the window title when I navigate the site's content with ajax. But that's not really the point, I just want to know if Google indexes these attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it won't be indexed.  The attribute itself will be cached with the page, but Google has no context of what the attribute or the value means, so it is meaningless to search engines.

Answer (score 7):

You should assume that all HTML content can be used to some extent by a search engine.

However, I would say almost invariably that visible content will be weighted much more heavily than invisible content. Even if Google *does* use data attributes in its weighting algorithm, you should make the content visible to users too

Comment: Ok. I guess another approach would be to include an <h1> for each of the gallery lists and then hide that element with CSS.

Comment: @StaffanEstberg I don't think Google is so stupid as not to notice, that you are hiding something with CSS. Yandex detects such things, for example. I think you can hide it with JS. But only until time, when spiders learn to execute JS on page they index.