# Can the data in Bootstrap's "popovers" plugin be seen by Google for SEO?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, seo, popover

I'm building a site based upon Twitter Bootstrap at the moment, and I've seen nothing discussed about this so far.

There is a function called "[popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)" that open up a little modal window when a link is rolled-over or clicked, kinda like a big tool-top.

On my site, there is lots of good info in here for the user (I have about 10 links that, when rolled over, each display about 50 words of explanatory info so 500 words total, all obviously related to my keywords).

The issue is that the data is called as follows:

`<a href="#" rel="popover" data-content="data data data lots of great data informative for the user explains things concisely wow what a great resource">Link name</a>`

Now I'm guessing that Google won't see the `data-content`, but correct me if I'm wrong. I can also call the data from javascript, but I'm fairly certain Google won't read that either.

Is there anything I can do to get this content seen? I'm going for usability rather than SEO-friendliness here, so it's no big deal but would be nice to get some extra love from google if I can.

EDIT: For instance, could I put the data as text in a hidden div, and then use javascript to call that data into the popover when the link is clicked? Or something similar?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174505/is-google-indexing-html-custom-data-attributes

Comment: Indeed, although I'm wondering if there's any way to get this data seen by robots rather than just hiding in data-content.

Answer (score 1):

So the consensus seems to be that Google will not understand this data while scanning your content. One approach that might add some benefit is to hide your content in divs on the page that are not visible to the user and then grab that content by id.

```
    <a href="#" rel="popover" data-trigger="click" data-popover-template="popoverTemplate">Link Name</a>
    <div id="popoverTemplate" style="display:none">
        data data data lots of great data informative for the user explains things concisely wow what a great resource
    </div>

<script>
$(function(){
     var popoverOptions = {
        placement: 'right',
        trigger: 'manual',
        html: true,
        content: ''
    };

    $('a[rel="popover"]').popover(popoverOptions).click(function(e) {
          var $popover = $(this).data('popover');
          var contentTemplate = $(this).data('popover-template');
          $popover.options.content = $('#'+contentTemplate).html();
          $(this).popover('toggle');
       });
 });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/billpull/PmP93/1/

how much of an effect this will have on SEO I am not sure.

Comment: This is a great solution to the problem, but I had a really hard time implementing it. It turns out that Bootstrap has changed the way they store the popover data, so you need to change this line:

```var $popover = $(this).data('popover');``` to ```var $popover = $(this).data('bs.popover');```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the inner workings of Google, but technically the "data-content" attribute is still a part of the html document. Regardless of whether or not it is currently visible by the end-user.