# Intentionally Hiding a Div from Indexing

Tags: html

I've published a site with an animated "typer" script. My concern is— I want to keep the div from indexing, as Google might see this as keyword-stuffing.

Can you think of a way to code this appropriately, where:

1. One H1 sentence is displayed for SEO purposes.

   `example: **You deserve a website.**`
2. The rest of the 'mad-lib' content isn't indexed.

code:

`<div class="center-logo">
    <h1 class="is-for">
    You deserve <br>a <i data-typer-targets="better,better-working,better-looking,faster,stronger,longer,smiling,happier,sweet-smelling,hotter,sleeker,flatter,prettier,schmancy,bolder,blacker,braver,brighter,cleaner,cleverer,cooler,funnier,healthier,wetter,warmer,thicker,taller,sweeter,smoother,kinder,fairer,more handsome,more helpful,fitter - happier - more productive,harder - better - faster - stronger,work is never over,more caffeinated,make - my - neighbors - jealous,make - Mom - proud">
    </i> website.</h1>
    </div>`

Comment: @Shomz it's not untended as such. See homepage on squareflair.com thx

Comment: You can insert it using JavaScript after that the document loads.

Comment: @CHAMMEMRaed Google's crawler also executes JavaScript.

Comment: @GolezTrol True, but you can always wait for a particular user interaction to trigger the function that loads the content

Comment: Interesting ideas on JS. If it came to that, I would re-design rather than chance it.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't index custom data attributes like `data-typer-targets`, so the code you posted should be safe. The keywords are not in the content, but in a custom attribute that is hidden to the readers too. I'm pretty sure Google doesn't see this as keyword-stuffing.

This is confirmed by the answer here: [Is Google indexing html custom data attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174505/is-google-indexing-html-custom-data-attributes)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @GolezTrol